# Word VBA Listbox to delete certain sections in document does not delete

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

The goal of this Userform VBA macro is loop through a document, capture the heading numbers and text that utilize the "Header 1", "Heading 2", and "Heading 3" styles and give the user the option of deleting those sections from the document. There are toggles to include a section, exclude a section, Include all sections, and exclude all sections.

My problem is that when I exclude certain sections, it doesn't exclude the sections. My goal is to get it to delete the section and also to delete any multilevels in that section (e.g., if I exclude section 1.4, then section 1.4.1 and 1.4.2 are also deleted.

Any help would be appreciated - I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

[Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF38n.png)

```
Sub Cancel_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim excluded As Boolean
    
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
        excluded = True
        For j = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
            If Me.ListBox1.List(j, 0) = "Include" And Me.ListBox1.List(j, 1) = i Then
                excluded = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        
        If excluded Then
            Dim para As Paragraph
            Dim headingLevel As Integer
            For Each para In ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Range.Paragraphs
                If para.style = "Heading 1" Or para.style = "Header 2" Or para.style = "Header 3" Then
                    headingLevel = para.OutlineLevel
                    If headingLevel = wdOutlineLevel1 Or headingLevel = wdOutlineLevelBodyText Then
                        para.Range.Delete
                    ElseIf headingLevel = wdOutlineLevel2 Then
                        Dim nextPara As Paragraph
                        Set nextPara = para.Next
                        Do While nextPara.OutlineLevel >= wdOutlineLevel3
                            nextPara.Range.Delete
                            Set nextPara = nextPara.Next
                        Loop
                        para.Range.Delete
                    ElseIf headingLevel = wdOutlineLevel3 Then
                        para.Range.Delete
                    End If
                End If
            Next para
        End If
    Next i
    
    Unload Me
End Sub






Function IsSelected(index As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) And i + 1 = index Then
    IsSelected = True
Exit Function
End If
Next i
End Function

Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim para As Paragraph
Dim num As String
Me.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "40pt;40pt;250pt"
For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
If para.style = "Heading 1" Or para.style = "Header 2" Or para.style = "Header 3" Then
num = para.Range.ListFormat.ListString
If para.style = "Header 2" Then
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem ""
    Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 0) = "Include"
    Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = num
    Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = Left(para.Range.Text, Len(para.Range.Text) - 1)
ElseIf para.style = "Header 3" Then
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem ""
    Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 0) = "Include"
    Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = num
    Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = Left(para.Range.Text, Len(para.Range.Text) - 1)

Else
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem ""
    Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 0) = "Include"
    Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = num
    Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = Left(para.Range.Text, Len(para.Range.Text) - 1)
End If
End If
Next para
End Sub

Sub IncludeSection_Click()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
ListBox1.List(i, 0) = "Include"
End If
Next i
End Sub

Sub ExcludeSection_Click()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
ListBox1.List(i, 0) = ""


End If
Next i
End Sub

Private Sub ExcludeAll_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        ListBox1.List(i, 0) = ""
        ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub IncludeAll_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        ListBox1.List(i, 0) = "Included"
        ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

I tried selecting all the sections and excluding them - when I do that it deletes everything.